# anyone have an in-memory AspnetMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-membership

I'm running some acceptance tests, and would rather not bother re-creating the user database across runs.  It'd be fine if the user store was reset when the application pool was reset, so an in-memory membership provider would be nice.

Comment: have you looked at using Moq?

Comment: its for acceptance testing, not unit testing

Answer (score 0):

I would look at implementing your own custom membership provider implementing just the methods you need for acceptance testing.

Here's an example of implementing a custom provider: http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/